Calculate $\mathbb E [\mathbb E[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb E [T | X_T = n]\mathbb P[X_T=n] | T]]$, where $T\sim$ Exp and $(X_t)$ a Poisson process
Assume $T \sim \text{Exp}(\mu)$ and let $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. I am trying to calculate $\mathbb E [\mathbb E[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb E [T | X_T = n]\mathbb P[X_T=n] | T]]$.
Is there an easy way to do this? The way I tried seems complicated and I'm not able to finish it:
I used $X_T=n \iff J_n \leq T < J_{n+1}$, where $J_i$ is the time of the $i$-th jump of the process, to calculate  $\mathbb E [T | X_T = n] = \mathbb E[T \mathbb 1_{[J_n \leq T < J_{n+1}]}]/\mathbb P[J_n \leq T < J_{n+1}]$ and found that this is a continuous function of $T$ and is thus measurable w.r.t. $T$, which means I can pull it out of the conditional expectation $\mathbb E [... | T]$ (together with the sum, which I think would be justified using Fubini's theorem).
If I could then replace $ \mathbb E [T | X_T = n]$ by $T$, I could calculate the sum, but I have no idea how to justify this and the $T$ I want to replace it with is also just a guess.
For context, I am trying to solve this problem here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459726/poisson-process-combined-waiting-time), but with $T$ being the above exponential random variable instead of a fixed constant:

Passengers arrive at a railway station according to a homogeneous Poisson process with rate λ. At the beginning (time 0), there are no passengers at the station. The train departs at time T. Denote by W be the total waiting time of all passengers arrived up to the departure of the train. Compute E(W).


First, by the tower property, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left.\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] \mathbb{P}(X_T=n)\right|T\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] \mathbb{P}(X_T=n)\right].$$
Now, we have $\mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] = \mathbb{E}[T 1_{X_T=n}]/\mathbb{P}(X_T=n)$, so $\mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] \mathbb{P}(X_T=n) = \mathbb{E}[T 1_{X_T=n}].$  Therefore, we can compute
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] \mathbb{P}(X_T=n) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb{E}[T1_{X_T=n}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty  T 1_{X_T = n} \right] \tag{by Tonelli} \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[T \sum_{n=0}^\infty  1_{X_T = n} \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[T].
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb{E}[T|X_T=n] \mathbb{P}(X_T=n)\right] = \mathbb{E}[T].$$

Thanks for your answer! I just noticed that I missed an $n$ when I asked my question, so what I actually wanted was $\mathbb E [\mathbb E[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\mathbb E [T | X_T = n]\mathbb P[X_T=n] | T]]$. As far as I can see that doesn't change your answer except that in the end we get $\mathbb E[T X_T]$. Do you by any chance have an idea how I could calculate that? Since $T$ and $X_T$ aren't independent I don't just get $\mathbb E[T] \mathbb E[X_T]$. Thank you!

@hm1912  It would depend on the joint distribution of $T$ and $X$.

I failed to mention that $T$ and $X$ are independent, but I think I just got it: Using the first result from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939444/law-of-total-probability-in-continous-case#939646 I can write $\mathbb E[T X_T] = \int \mathbb E[T X_T | T = t] \mathbb P[T=t] dt$, but since $T$ and $X$ are independent, $\mathbb E[T X_T | T = t] = \mathbb E[t X_t | T = t] = \mathbb E[t X_t] = t^2 \lambda$. So the integral should then be $\mathbb E[T^2 \lambda]$. Does that sound right to you?

@hm1912  $X_T$ is the amount of poisson arrivals in time $T$ . That is $(X_T\mid T)\sim\mathcal {Pois}(\lambda T)$ . So, then: $$\begin{align}\Bbb E(TX_T) &=\Bbb E(T\Bbb E(X_T\mid T)) \&= \Bbb E(\lambda T^2)\ &=\lambda(\Bbb{Var}(T)+\Bbb E(T)^2)\&=\lambda(\tfrac 1{\mu^2}+(\tfrac 1\mu)^2)\&=\dfrac{2\lambda}{\mu^2} \end{align}$$

@GrahamKemp That makes sense, thank you!
